# Optgroup behaving differently in Chrome than IE

Tags: html

I have an array of strings "GlobalObject" that is used to load values into a select, and the following code works perfectly in Chrome but not in IE 11. I am not sure why. The strings are ordered such as:

14000 // optgroup

14239

14238

14238
etc.

```
 for(var i = 1; i < GlobalObject[0].length; i++) {
    var opt = GlobalObject[0][i];
    var subString = opt.substring(opt.length - 4, opt.length);

    if (i != GlobalObject[0].length -1 ) {
    var opt2 = GlobalObject[0][i+1];
    var subString2 = opt2.substring(opt2.length - 4, opt2.length);
    }
    else {}


    if (subString != "0000") {
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + opt;
    el.value =  opt;
    newOptGroup.appendChild(el); 
    }

    else  {

    var newOptGroup = document.createElement("OPTGROUP");
    newOptGroup.label = opt;
    newOptGroup.value = opt;
    }

    if (subString2 == "0000" || i == GlobalObject[0].length-1 ) {
    console.log("here");
    ChannelList.add(newOptGroup);

   }
   }
```

It inserts the first optgroup and then nothing after that in IE11.

Comment: You mix `option`s and `optgroup`s. If a `optgroup` started then you have to add `option`s to it, not to `select` element.

Comment: @Alex Kudryashev what is the syntax to add options to an optgroup with javascript

Comment: See this example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_optgroup_create

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Code edited and still the same problem essentially. Works fine in chrome.

Comment: See my answer. Works everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working example. I hope you can adapt it to you case.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<select id="mySelect" size="6">
</select>

<script>
var arr=['1111'/*not optgroup*/,'0123'/*optgroup*/,'1234','2345','0567','5678','6789'];
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var gr = null;//future optgroup
    for(var i=0,n=arr.length;i<n;i++){
      if(arr[i].indexOf('0')==0){//starts with 0 - optgroup
        gr = document.createElement("OPTGROUP");
        gr.label = arr[i];
        x.appendChild(gr);
      }
      else {
        var op = document.createElement("option");
        op.textContent = arr[i];
        op.value = arr[i];
        if(gr)//optgroup exists
           gr.appendChild(op);
        else //optgroup not exists
           x.appendChild(op);
     }
    }//for
}//myFunction
</script>
```

```js
var arr=['1111','0123','1234','2345','0567','5678','6789'];
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var gr = null;
    for(var i=0,n=arr.length;i<n;i++){
      if(arr[i].indexOf('0')==0){
        gr = document.createElement("OPTGROUP");
        gr.label = arr[i];
        x.appendChild(gr);
      }
      else {
        var op = document.createElement("option");
        op.textContent = arr[i];
        op.value = arr[i];
        if(gr)
           gr.appendChild(op);
        else
           x.appendChild(op);
     }
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<select id="mySelect" size="6">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok problem fixed with the following code:

```
for(var i = 1; i < GlobalObject[0].length; i++) {
    var opt = GlobalObject[0][i];
    var subString = opt.substring(opt.length - 4, opt.length);

    if (i != GlobalObject[0].length -1 ) {
    var opt2 = GlobalObject[0][i+1];
    var subString2 = opt2.substring(opt2.length - 4, opt2.length);
    }
    else {}


    if (subString != "0000") {
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + opt;
    el.value =  opt;
    newOptGroup.appendChild(el); 
    }

    else  {

    var newOptGroup = document.createElement("OPTGROUP");
    newOptGroup.label = opt;
    newOptGroup.value = opt;
    }

    if (subString2 == "0000" || i == GlobalObject[0].length-1 ) {
    console.log("here");
    ChannelList.appendChild(newOptGroup);

   }
   }
```